# Configuring Application Endpoints in AppFabric

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I am using AppFabric 1.1 in IIS 7.5 on windows 7 machine to host my Workflows as service. Though I am able to see System endpoints and Application Default endpoints in AppFabric dashboard in IIS, I am not able to see my endpoints that I defined in Web.config file of the application.Also when I add Service Reference in my client projects, I can only see default endpoint configuration values provided by AppFabric. It appears that AppFabric is ignoring <'Service'> tag values in application's web.config file.What could be the reason? Is there something I might have missed ? Any suggestions are greately appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. When I changed the service name (in service tag element) exactly as it is in appfabric dashboard for the service, the application endpoints are showing up.